# ajax insert and select consecutive not working fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making a pos system. looking for a product in the search bar or entering the barcode, I create ajax requests:
add the product to the cart (insert in pos)
load the list in the cart (select pos)

the problem I'm seeing is that when I load the list, sometimes it skips the update request.
i tried to use

```
$.when(func of add product).then(func of load list);
```

and

```
$.ajax(... func of add product).done(func of load list);
```

but nothing.
How is it possible?

Comment: You're right it is probably a timing issue, however, we cannot tell because we cannot reproduce your problem. See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the thing you call a 'POS' is in reality a database, then the problem could be that the database update hasn't finished before you retrieve the list from it.

Comment: i solved using setTimeout of 200ms, i add product in db and load list after 200ms.
can be good solution?

Comment: i tried and works perfectly

Comment: It might work, but it is probably not a reliable solution when the server comes under load.

Comment: seems you might need something synchronous instead of asynchronous.